# css img on navbar jumps when hover

Tags: html, css

I'm new at CSS and I'm trying to get this vertical right side menu to work.
The problem: when I hover over the images they get bigger (this is intended) but when I hover between the images everything seems to jump and I can't figure out why.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #eee4e4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: solid 2px blue;
}

img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

img:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

li:hover {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Social Media NAV -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook1.svg" alt="Facebook"></img>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter1.svg" alt="Twitter"></img>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram1.svg" alt="Instagram"></img>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/whatsapp1.svg" alt="Whatsapp"></img>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you also have a `li:hover` that is affecting the padding.

Maybe an alternative solution could be using `transform` in the `<img>` and remove the `li:hover`

```
img:hover {
   transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that the you might want to trigger the style on hover of the entire li rather than just hovering on the image  - two ways to achieve this - since the img is wrapped in an a element - make it display: block to fill the entire li and put the style rule on that ... nv li a {disaply: block} ....  nav li a:hover img{ transform: scale(1.2) }... or just apply the hover to the li itself  - nav li:hover img {transform: scale(1.2)...} - always remember that a elements are inline and therefore hovering on the whitespce of the li around the a will not trigger the style rule